# How to copy file after finding it

Tags: linux, bash, maven

I am trying to create a script which will execute the following actions
1- execute mvn clean 
2- execute mvn package 
3- find the .jar file and move it to a destination folder passed as an arg on the command line

```
#!/bin/bash
destination=“$1”

#Clean
mvn clean

#Package
mvn package

#Transfer the generated jar file to the destination folder
find . -name “*.jar” | xargs cp -t $destination
```

This is running the maven scripts fine but when I go to the destination folder the file is not copied. 
I know that the .jar file is there and is found when I print out the result of `find . -name “*.jar”`:

```
./target/QuoteTool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But the step of copying the file is not happening correctly.

Any help much appreciated.

Note: I am using a Mac

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `xargs` but just use the `-exec` option within `find` command itself.

Also you have Unicode Windows style double-quotes (see [Unicode Utilities](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp?a=%22&r=None)), `“*.jar”` should have been used as `"*.jar"`

```
find . -type f -name "*.jar" -exec cp -t "$destination" "{}" +
```

In the above example, `cp` with `+` over `exec` will *avoid* forking a `cp` for each of the `jar` file found, but rather copies all the files found to destination in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to rewrite the line in the following way

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec cp {} $destination \;
```

it gives you the result you would like to have

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `-e` option with `xargs` to look something like

```
find . -name “*.jar” | xargs -e cp $destination/
```